# is it possible to assign id name to a variable and use it in a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, iteration, onkeyup

I am creating an html form that will take quantity values in input for items and calculate the individual total cost and show it adjacent to each input box and show the grand total at the bottom of the form. I am doing it with JS and KeyUp function and trying to iterate the function.

My HTML

```
<p><span>T-Shirts </span> <input type="number" name ="tshirts" value="0" id="tshirts">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="tshirtscost">0</span><br></p>
<p><span>Shirts </span> <input type="number" name ="shirts" value="0" id="shirts">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="shirtscost">0</span><br></p>
<p><span>Kurtas </span> <input type="number" name ="kurtas" value="0" id="kurtas">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="kurtascost">0</span><br></p>

<div id="totalcost"></div>
```

My JS

```
var item = ["T-Shirt/s","Shirt/s","Kurta/s"];
var itemcost=100;
var text = "";
var i;

for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
 text = item[i].replace(/ |-|&|\//g, '').toLowerCase();

 itemid="#" + text;
 itemclass="." + text + "cost";

 $(itemid).keyup(function(){
    var x = $(itemid).val();
    $(itemclass).css("background-color", "pink").html("Rs."+ (x * itemcost));
    totalcost();

});

function totalcost(){
var tot=$('#tshirts').val()*itemcost + $('#shirts').val()*itemcost + $('#kurtas').val();
    $("#totalcost").css("background-color", "pink").html("<span style='font-weight:700'>Total Cost : </span>Rs."+tot);
  }
}
```

The idea to iterate the js operation is because I have lot many more items for input and calculation in the form.

However, I am not sure trying to create a variable with a class name and using it in the function is a possibility. But if something similar can be done, it will save me writing lots of lines of code for each item.

This code is not working. Probably for obvious reasons that I cant see. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40818817/2545680) for the general approach. what's `itemcost1` in your example?

Comment: Hi...sorry that was a typo..it is itemcost....have edited it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use inner function because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

In you example, you're updating two variables in the loop - `itemid` and `itemclass`. But every function you're registering in `.keyup` will remember not the values for these variables, but the variable itself. And since after the last loop these variables will contain the last value, all callbacks will use the last value of `itemid` and `itemclass`.
That's why you need to use inner function, so inner function will have `id` and `cls` variables created each time with the correct value.
What are're looking is probably this:

```
$(itemid).keyup((function (id, cls) {
    return function () {
        var x = $(id).val();
        $(cls).css("background-color", "pink").html("Rs." + (x * itemcost));
        totalcost();
    }
}(itemid, itemclass)));
```

I've created [a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/REcVxpuZ1I5s4ltbEErV?p=preview) to show that.

Comment: @user3526204, it's working fine for me, please see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/REcVxpuZ1I5s4ltbEErV?p=preview).

Comment: is this line <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> making it work... ? Let me check...

Comment: Yes ! it is ! Only thing is the final total is showing multiplied by 10...let try to fix that.... Thanks a ton ! Choosing this as the answer.

Comment: Just one query....why is itemid working in the line $(itemid).keyup((function (id, cls) { ...... but not in........ $(itemid).keyup(function(){
    var x = $(itemid).val(); ?

Comment: I got it, I have to use var x = $(this).val(); ...still figuring out why $(itemclass).css("background-color", "pink").html("Rs."+ (x * itemcost)); won't work... ..

Comment: Got that too...had a stray apostrophe in the definition of the variable...thanks all guys..

Comment: Only thing is, the itemclass is picking up the last class name in the loop instead of the current class name ..in my version. And the totalcost() is showing the figure multiplied 10 times in both the versions (mine and the accepted answer) !

Comment: @user3526204, yes, [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) about why this happens. That's why I used [IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to wrap correct `itemid` and `itemclass` and access them inside the function as `id` and `cls`

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Got it. but just out of curiosity, was wondering what exactly was wrong with $(itemid).keyup(function(){
    var x = $(itemid).val(); var x = $(itemid).val(); } why that will not work ? Though the itemid variable has the id name in it. Is there some way that could work as well ?

Comment: Reason I am asking is, I am trying to get the totalcost() also to iterate through the item values and calculate the grand total without having to add each input value with id name. I have about 50 items and these may change later.

Comment: @user3526204, have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)?

Comment: Yes, I did but honestly couldn't really relate...my bad...not too good in js ...sorry :( It was way beyond my mental capabilty...

Comment: @user3526204, I added some details to the answer. Please check.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks a ton. I am now working on trying to make the totalcost() work with looping too.... :)

Answer (score 1):

You may register an event to all the `input` elements without iterating through each one of them manually.

```
jQuery('p > input').keyup(function() {
  // handle keyup event
});
```

This piece of code assigns an enclosure to be executed on `keyUp` to all `p > input` elements **in the page**. I would personally recommend enclosing the items I am addressing inside a container, to prevent targeting others you did not originally intended.

---

To access the adjacent `span`'s, you may use many different methods, this uses [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/), for example:

```
jQuery('p > input').keyup(function(e) {
  // handle keyup event
  jQuery(e.target).next().css('color', 'fuchsia');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes things simpler. However, am still looking for a solution for the calculation function.

Comment: `totalcost()`? It should work. Could you provide more details? I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes ....at the bottom ...as well as the individual total that is to be calculated and rendered next to the qty input box..

Comment: you see the span after the input in the html   and  x * itemcost in the js ?